# How to sizeable line using Javascript and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I was using drag and drop using Javascript and HTML5

Consider, I have 2 area ( Black area and White area)
In which, black area is area that have images/text to drag
White area is area to drop object (text/image)

In this case, I want to drag and drop a line ( the line is drop constitute copy of line from black area)

How to sizeable copy of line in white area (drop area) , after I drag and drop the line?

Given the answer with Javascript and HTML5 code, Thanks a lot

Comment: well, what did you try already? any code samples you can provide? maybe a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

can you please provide us maybe the source of the project you're trying to do to give me and other's a better understanding of what you're having problems with.

Comment: This is my work

Before drag and Drop: <http://cl.ly/image/0O3w2y1k0U3b>

After drag and drop: <http://cl.ly/image/0C210U3m0d0Z>

I have 2 area, black area and White area, in which white area is area to drop.

After drag and drop, i have problem that copy images(in white area) can't move/drag in white area and How to sizeable line in white area?

this is to aim get functionality like modeling tool UML

Comment: Okay, so for what I've gathered you're trying to move the images into the white space around? Sorry if I've misread.

Comment: I want to try making the functionality like Use case diagram (UML) but using HTML5 and Javascript code...

And I missing to drag/ move the copy of image/ line in white area after I drop...

I was try to think the deep, but I can't.
Because I'm not a programmer :(

This is my HTML5 and Javascript code...
Javascript: (http://cl.ly/image/3J1u101p0S1e)
HTML5     : (http://cl.ly/image/2z041f240f3U)